Is it possible to reliably test for running on SF Mobile App from Desktop Brower?
I've been using Chrome Developer Tools to check how components render on a mobile experience.  But, it doesn't behave exactly like the mobile App.  For one thing, SF still thinks its Theme4d instead of Theme4t.  And components will still think they are a larger format so they'll render even if they aren't configured to render on one.
